# run unix commands on ruby window

Tags: ruby, shell, cygwin

I have a shell script written by Unix commands, and now I want to run this script file (*.sh) on Ruby command prompt window. Anybody please guide me a solution ? many thanks.

Comment: You mean, you want to run a shell script from irb? If so, just type system "./script.sh"

Comment: Oh, sorry there is typo in my question, I mean I want to run a shell script (*.sh) including Unix commands on the Ruby command prompt window. Currently, I cannot do this because Ruby does not recognize Unix commands included in my shell script. Thanks.

Comment: More info is that I observed this message displayed right after I type the syntax as your suggestion: C:\test>system "./tests.sh"
the error I got is "'system' is not recognized as an internal or external command".
operable program or batch file.

Comment: You are on a DOS prompt in Windows, not Ruby. Are you sure this is about Ruby?

Comment: Yes, sure, I'm on Ruby command prompt window "ruby 1.9.3p327 (2012-11-10) [i386-mingw32]"

Comment: Hahahahah :-))))) rofl ... long time since I last typed _rofl_ :-))))) ... sorry, I shouldn't laugh, but ... are you sure you are not faking it?

Comment: I'm trying to run a Unix script file from "Start Command Prompt with Ruby" window, but it seems that Unix commands are not recognized when running from this window, I'm only able to run it successfully from Cygwin. Sorry, if the info is not clear enough for you to help me out on this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use backticks or the `%x{...}` syntax to execute external programs:

```
output = %x{./tests.sh}
```

See http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-60